# Can I make my regex split the punctuation marks from my special words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
"By signing in, I agree to the {{#a}}[Terms of Use](https://www.example.com/termsofuse){{/a}} and {{#a}}[Privacy Policy](https://www.example.com/privacy){{/a}}."
```

And I am using the following regex to split the words while considering `{{#a}}[Terms of Use](https://www.example.com/termsofuse){{/a}}` and `{{#a}}[Privacy Policy](https://www.example.com/privacy){{/a}}` as whole words.

```
\s+(?![^\[]*\])
```

My problem is that my current regex does not remove the full stop at the end of `{{#a}}[Privacy Policy](https://www.example.com/privacy){{/a}}.`. Ideally I would like my regex to split full stops, exclamation marks and question marks. That being said, I'm not sure how would I differentiate between a full stop at the end of the word and a full stop that is part of the URL.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Just use `string.match(/\{\{#a}}.*?\{\{\/a}}/g)` or this regex: `/\{\{#a}}\[[^\]]*]\([^)]*\)\{\{\/a}}/g`

Comment: Try `text.match(/\{\{#a\}\}[^]*?\{\{\/a\}\}|[^\s\p{S}\p{P}]+|[\p{S}\p{P}]/gu)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a variation of the following regular expression:

```
\s+(?![^\[]*\])|(?=[\.?!](?![a-zA-Z0-9_%-]))
```

The new part being the alternation of `(?=[\.?!](?![a-zA-Z0-9_%-]))` at the end. It performs a positive lookahead of a period, question mark or bang, using a negative lookahead to make sure it's not followed by a URL-ish looking character. You may need to adjust that character class in brackets to contain the characters you want to consider part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.split` you will be better off using `.match` here using this regex:

```
\{\{#a}}.*?\{\{\/a}}/g
```

This matches `{{#a}}` followed by 0 or of any character followed by `{{/a}}`.

or else you may use this more strict regex match:

```
\{\{#a}}\[[^\]]*]\([^)]*\)\{\{\/a}}
```

Here:

- `\[[^\]]*]`: Matches `[...]` substring
- `\([^)]*\)`: Matches `(...)` substring

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gyuXD8/1)

```js
var string = "By signing in, I agree to the {{#a}}[Terms of Use](https://www.example.com/termsofuse){{/a}} and {{#a}}[Privacy Policy](https://www.example.com/privacy){{/a}}.";
console.log( string.match(/\{\{#a}}.*?\{\{\/a}}/g) );
```